# Why can't Windows view new files on my USB drive?

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-explorer, file-transfer, chromebook

I'm trying to transfer files from my chromebook to my PC (windows 10, no internet connection) using a USB flash drive.  The files I have transferred to my USB drive show up on my chromebook's file explorer and can be opened and used as usual from there, but when I plug my USB drive into my PC, none of the new files I transferred show up.  I have *show hidden files* on, and they don't appear when I try to search or restart my PC.  Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I just tried transferring a new set of files over and they showed up just fine.  The files that weren't showing up before still aren't showing up in windows and show up just fine on chrome OS.

EDIT 2: The files also don't show up on another PC of mine.  I created zip archive and was able to transfer the files fine, but I still want to know how to fix this so I don't have to archive all my files.

Comment: What file system has the USB been formatted with?

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know, I'll check in a few minutes

Comment: @DavidPostill FAT32.  also see edit

Comment: If you create a copy of the file, on the Chromebook and then transfer the copy to the flash drive, does it show up?

Comment: @Ramhound No, those files don't show up.  I tried again on another PC and they don't show up on there either

Comment: Try seeing if small files are more likely to be seen on Windows than big ones.  Perhaps you're removing the flash drive before the file is completely copied over.

Comment: @AndrewM. no, otherwise I wouldn't be able to see the files and interact with them on my chromebook

Comment: Oh right.  It has to be something specific about your USB stick or less likely the USB port on your Chromebook.  I suggest trying another USB stick, reformatting this one, or trying a different port.